# What types do I need to use for $location and $stateParams services

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am rewring the AngularJS (1.5 version) application using TypeScript. Which types do I need to use when I am injecting the `$location` and `$stateParams` services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **$location**

```
//constructor param:
$location: ng.ILocationService
```

> **$stateParams**

`$stateParams` is specifically of type `any` so you can be more specific with your definition:

```
//param definition:
type RouteParams = {
  // whatever params are being passed in
}
//constructor param:
$stateParams: RouteParam
```